# Base64 to String in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, base64, todataurl

I have this code that transforms an image url to base64, it works perfectly but I haven't found a way to convert the result to a string, I need to convert it to a string since I have to POST via an API, any idea I'm doing wrong? :(

```js
const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = reject
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  }))


toDataURL('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0')
  .then(dataUrl => {
    console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl)
  })
```

most likely it's something super simple that I'm failing :(

Comment: `dataUrl` is already a string. What's the question? Replace the console log with `console.log('RESULT:', typeof dataUrl)` and you'll see that it's already a `string`

Comment: I took the liberty to turn your code into a live snippet. It shows that the result is in fact a base64 encoded string (+ some data url syntax)

Comment: is `atob` and [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) all you need?

Comment: I expressed myself wrong, what I need is to pass the result that the console.log gives me to show it on the screen as a string

Answer (score 0):

"what I need is to pass the result that the console.log gives me to show it on the screen as a string"

then just do that

```js
const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = reject
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  }))


toDataURL('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0')
  .then(dataUrl => {
    document.getElementById("blob-string").innerText = dataUrl;
  })
```

```html
<p id="blob-string"></p>
```

Comment: query, can I save the result in a variable? for example "const image64 = .... " ? I appreciate your time!

Comment: `reader.result` has 3 types. `FileReader.result: string | ArrayBuffer | null`.